# Изменение url для отправки DELETE запроса

Tags: javascript, url

**Форма:**

```
      <table id="adminTable" class="table_dark" align="center">
                        <caption>FLIGHT MANAGEMENT</caption>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="3">Navigation flight</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <form method="POST" action="/flight/add" id="addForm">
                                <td colspan="3">
                                    <input type="text" name="navigation" id="navigation" value="">
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Add flight" id="addButton">
                                </td>
                            </form>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Navigation</th>
                            <th>TeamId</th>
                            <th>Select</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        <form method="DELETE" action="/flight/delete/" id="deleteForm">
                            <c:forEach var="flight" items="${flights}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${flight.id}</td>
                                    <td>${flight.navigation}</td>
                                    <td>${flight.team.id}</td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="id${flight.id}" id="${flight.id}" value="${flight.id}"></td>
                                    <td><input type="submit" value="Delete flight" id="deleteButton"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </form>
                    </table>
```

**Контроллер:**

```
   function deleteButtonClickHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var adminTable = document.getElementById('adminTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var deleteForm = document.getElementById('deleteForm');
    var flightId = 0;
    var check;
    for (var i = 3; i < adminTable.length; i++) {
        var td = adminTable[i].querySelectorAll("td")[3];
        var checkbox = td.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']");
        if (checkbox.checked) {
           check = true;
           flightId = checkbox.value;
           alert(flightId);
           break;
        }
    }

    if(check) {
        deleteForm = document.getElementById('deleteForm');
        deleteForm.action = "/flight/delete/" + flightId;
        deleteForm.submit();
    }
    else {
        alert("Please check flight and then click on button")
    }

}
```

**Проблема**

Отправка происходит по url: http://localhost:8080/flight/delete/5?id5=5

*Необходимо*: http://localhost:8080/flight/delete/5

Comment: Как вы удаляете строки, если несколько флажков отмечено, каким запросом? И на какой надо исправить?

Comment: @br3t, )подразумевается, что отмечается одна

Comment: Хотел еще уточнить, с чем связано столь интересное решение в UI - и флажок отмечать, и кнопка удаления в каждой строке?

Comment: @br3t, с тем что занимаюсь бэкэндом)

Comment: так а вариант с только кнопкой "удалить" вы рассматривали или он от вас не зависит?

Comment: @br3t  уже сделал через 'radiobutton'. Возникает вопрос: как расположить эту одну кнопку, чтобы смотрелось все гармонично?

Comment: Кнопка остается для каждой строки, убирается radio. В какой строке кнопку нажали - по такому id и будет удаляться строка в базе

Comment: @br3t, логично спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Отрезольвил дублирующиеся id и убрал излишние блуждания по DOM. Выдираем id полетя для удаления из отмеченного флажка и подставляем в `action` формы, сам флажок удаляем из формы.

```js
function deleteButtonClickHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var deleteForm = document.getElementById('deleteForm');
  var checkboxes = deleteForm.querySelectorAll(".deleteCheckbox");
  for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if(checkboxes[i].checked) {
      var flightId = checkboxes[i].value;
      deleteForm.action = "/flight/delete/" + flightId;
      checkboxes[i].parentElement.removeChild(checkboxes[i]);
      deleteForm.submit();
      return true;
    }
  }
  alert("Please check flight and then click on button");
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form method="DELETE" action="/flight/delete/" id="deleteForm">
  <c:forEach var="flight" items="${flights}">
    <tr>
      <td>${flight.id}</td>
      <td>${flight.navigation}</td>
      <td>${flight.team.id}</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="deleteCheckbox" name="id${flight.id}" id="${flight.id}" value="${flight.id}"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Delete flight" class="deleteButton"></td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</form>
```

Comment: И получится url: http://localhost:8080/flight/delete/?id6=6, a нужно : http://localhost:8080/flight/delete/6

Comment: Обновил код, проверьте

Comment: Получается 5?id5=

Comment: @br3t не будет работать ваша проверка на выбранные checkbox

Comment: @studentST, аргументируйте

Comment: @bsuart, накидал ваш пример в статическом html http://br3t.org.ua/works/snippets/deleteForm.html , видимо, есть еще что-то, о чем вы не написали.

Comment: @br3t, все что есть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666143/Проверка-всех-checkbox-в-таблице-javascript

Comment: @bsuart, пример по ссылке работает у вас?

Comment: @br3t, пример по ссылке работает только на один checkbox - первый, так как только у него id на который навешен обработчик, остальное в следующем вопросе описал